# Antminer S1, how to mine on multiple pools

Tags: mining-pools, asic, miner-configuration

I have an ant s1 and I want to mine on 3 pools. We can set them in the miner configuration but  the antminer use only the first one. I guess it will use the second then the third one in case of failover.

Is there a way to make the antS1 mining simultaneous on the different pools?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite, however you can pool hop.
Check out [Bit Hopper](https://github.com/c00w/bitHopper)

this way you can maximize your mining profits, obviously you put other people at a disadvantage, but the pool operator should really take care of these exploits...

Comment: Lol ok thanks, I will check this but it was not really my intention to use any kind of exploits :)

Comment: Do you know how to use it on an Antminer s1 ?